# Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2, The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: .net, lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I'm try to implement NHibernate.Search to my web application,
i hvae done configurations and loaded packages to the the application from NuGet

But when I run the application it throws following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Lucene.Net, Version=2.9.2.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/SJ/Application/Solution/SJ.Web/ LOG: Initial
>   PrivatePath = D:\SJ\Application\Solution\SJ.Web\bin Calling
>   assembly : NHibernate.Search, Version=2.0.2.4000, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   D:\SJ\Application\Solution\SJ.Web\web.config LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/33aeca0d/35fb23ff/Lucene.Net.DLL. LOG: Attempting download
>   of new URL file:///C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/root/33aeca0d/35fb23ff/Lucene.Net/Lucene.Net.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///D:/SJ/Application/Solution/SJ.Web/bin/Lucene.Net.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY
>   TOKEN ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.

what is the reason to this error and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Please confirm you have installed version 2.9.2.2 from nuget, version might be different. You can use this command on package console install-package Lucene.Net -version 2.9.2.2

Comment: "Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: PUBLIC KEY TOKEN". Sounds like someone has compiled their own version of Lucene.Net.

Comment: Thanks vgSefa for considering my issue, previously used 3.0.3 But now I installed 2.9.2.2 but still getting same error, help me please

Comment: Thanks Simon Svensson, can you please tell me then what I can do for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some similar issue like this.

Try looking inside the `packages.config` and you should see the Lucene package and the version that is looking for when you compile. Try removing tha package from the Nuget Package Manager, and then, enter the packages.config and check if it's still pointing to some version. If it is the case, remove the reference inside this file, and then install again the version you want to use.

Then come here again and check if it's pointing the right version. I think that you can even change here the version in order to point to the right place.

I hope this helps

Thanks your answer is helpful, and I have fix my issue in following way, I removed all Lucene.Net from my solution and I have downloaded lucene.net from https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Search and added reference manually, Now  it is working

Comment: I am glad that you could fix your issue @Premila